# Class based component delay getting the props react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this class based component which has a prop of `projects` from the parent. On initial render the prop is null. This will be set after some calls in a lifecyclemethode in the parent component. But because this takes some time the `this.props.projects` on my child component is null at first. So if I set a state in my child component (null) and I try to set the state to `this.props.projects` I get null because I guess the props is not loaded in yet.

For now I do a setTimeout of a second to recieve the props and set the state. But I think this is not the best solution for this. How can I do this better?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'

class Show extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            project: null
        }

        this.run = this.run.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {

        this.run();

    }

    run() {

        setTimeout(() => {

            let project = this.props.projects.find((project) => {
                //Return project with the id equel to the match.params.id
                return project.id == this.props.match.params.id;
            });

            this.setState({project: project});

            console.log(this.state.project);


        }, 1000);

    }

    render() {

        return(

            <div className="container p-40">

                {this.state.project && this.state.project.name}

            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default Show;
```

If I don't set a timeout on the `this.run` function I get null back.

Parent

```
//Import react
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Import custom components
import Sidebar from './components/js/Sidebar'
import Dashboard from './components/js/Dashboard'
import Projects from './components/js/Projects'
import Show from './components/js/projects/Show2'

//Import styles
import './App.css';


//3rd party deps
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios'


class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      //Times / Time tracking
      times: [],
      timer: false,
      currentTimer: 0,

      //Current task
      currentTask: {
        id: 3,
        title: '',
        project_id: {
          id: '',
          name: '',
          color: ''
        },
        date: '',
        time_total: ''
      },

      //Projects
      projects: []

    }

    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
    this.addProject = this.addProject.bind(this);

  }

  addTask = (task) => {

    let newArray = this.state.times.slice();

    newArray.push(task);

    this.setState({times: newArray, currentTimer: 0, timer: false});

    clearInterval(this.timerID);

  }

  addProject = (project) => {

    let newArray = this.state.projects.slice();

    newArray.push(project);

    this.setState({ projects: newArray });

  }


  startTimer() {

    let sec = this.state.currentTimer;

    const start = Date.now();

    this.setState({ timer: true });

    this.timerID = setInterval(() => {


      let time = new Date() - (start - sec * 1000);

      this.setState({ currentTimer: Math.round(time / 1000)});


    }, 1000);

  }

  stopTimer() {

    this.setState({ timer: false });
    console.log('stopped');

    clearInterval(this.timerID);
    //Clear interval here

  }

  componentWillMount() {

    // Make a request for a user with a given ID
    axios.get('/Sample.json')
      .then((response) => {

        this.setState({times: response.data});

    });

    axios.get('/Projects.json')
      .then((response) => {

        this.setState({projects: response.data});

    });


  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Router>

        <div className="page-wrapper">

          <Sidebar />

          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Dashboard times={this.state.times} timer={this.state.timer} startTimer={this.startTimer} stopTimer={this.stopTimer} currentTimer={this.state.currentTimer} addTask={this.addTask} />} />
          <Route exact path="/projects" render={() => <Projects projects={this.state.projects} addProject={this.addProject} />} />
          <Route exact path="/projects/show/:id" render={(props) => <Show {...props} projects={this.state.projects} />} />

        </div>

      </Router>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `this.run()` in your componentDidUpdate() and check if the props have changed from null to set

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.projects !== prevProps.projects){
        this.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it is working with a hard reload, but it isn't working if I try to route to the view..

Answer (score 0):

So, there seems to be two cases that needs to be combined:

1. You can directly enter the url and access `"/projects/show/:id"`, which results in mounting of `<App/>` and `<Show/>` components one after the other while the state of `projects` in `<App/>` is an empty array since `axios.get('/Projects.json')` is not completed yet. Once it completes, the state gets updated and `<App/>` sends new `projects` props to `<Show/>` component. In this case, you can use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to compare the new and previous props and run your `this.run()` method.
2. You can first enter the url `"/"` or `"/projects"` and load `<App/>` component and after some time move to `/projects/show/:id` by an action like click or so. In this case, the `projects` state in `<App/>` may already be updated, and `projects` props (not empty array at this moment) is ready to be passed to `<Show/>` component. So at this case, with the first mount and render of  `<Show/>` component, the `projects` props has an actual array consisting values. You can handle this on `componentWillMount()` method and run `this.run()` here since there won't be any update on props later and `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` will not trigger since `axios.get('/Projects.json')` already completed long time ago.

So, I suggest you handle both of the cases, as it should be by using both `componentWillMount()` and `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` methods and checking if `projects` props has value such as this:

```
componentWillMount() {
        // check if projects props is not an empty array at initial load
        if (this.props.projects.length > 0) {
            this.run(this.props.projects);
        }
    }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // check if new and old projects props are different
        if (nextProps.projects.length > 0 && (nextProps.projects !== this.props.projects)) {
            this.run(nextProps.projects);
        }
    }

// and finally update your run() method
run(projects) {
    let project = projects.find((project) => {
        return project.id == this.props.match.params.id;
    });
    this.setState({project: project});
}
```